# Quorum quickstart Error - Docker compose: expected a mapping or list of mappings for merging, but found scalar

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, quorum, consensys-truffle

I'm trying to setup ConsenSys Quorum for the first time, and I run into an error while following the quickstart [tutorial](https://consensys.net/quorum/products/guides/getting-started-with-consensys-quorum/).

I follow the following steps to generate the error:

1. `npx quorum-dev-quickstart`
2. Which Ethereum client would you like to run? Default: (1) **My answer: 1**

   1. Hyperledger Besu
   2. GoQuorum
3. Do you want to try out Codefi Orchestrate? Note: choosing yes will direct you to a login/registration page. [Y/n] **My answer: n**
4. Do you wish to enable support for private transactions? [Y/n] **My answer: y**
5. Do you wish to enable support for logging with Splunk or ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash & Kibana)? Default: (1) **My answer: 3**

   1. None
   2. Splunk
   3. ELK
6. Where should we create the config files for this network? Please
   choose either an empty directory, or a path to a new directory that does not yet exist. Default: ./quorum-test-network
   **./quorum-test-network**
7. ✅ Installation complete.
   To start your test network, run 'run.sh' in the directory, './quorum-test-network'
8. `cd quorum-test-network`
9. `./run.sh`

Error on terminal:

```
*************************************
Quorum Dev Quickstart
*************************************
Start network
--------------------
Starting network...
ERROR: yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 383, column 5
expected a mapping or list of mappings for merging, but found scalar
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 253, column 19
ERROR: yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 383, column 5
expected a mapping or list of mappings for merging, but found scalar
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 253, column 19
*************************************
Quorum Dev Quickstart 
*************************************
----------------------------------
List endpoints and services
----------------------------------
JSON-RPC HTTP service endpoint                 : http://localhost:8545
JSON-RPC WebSocket service endpoint            : ws://localhost:8546
Web block explorer address                     : http://localhost:25000/
```

To see the docker-compose file click [here](https://gist.github.com/BravoNatalie/a800bd292c07ed6887f70f4e9a6dc592).

Comment: How do you use these three image files to reproduce the issue?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], with any relevant application code and the errors you get, as text and not as images?

Comment: I just update the question with all the steps I take. I would be very glad if you could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in v0.0.26

The github issue you posted has been updated https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum-dev-quickstart/issues/81. Could you verify please and let us know if this is still an issue

Cheers